# Check if a float number is in a dictionary key in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dict like this `tmp_dic = {'0.0': 'val0', '1': 'val1', 'key3': 'val2'}` . Now during parsing a file, I wanna check if for instance a float value of lets say 1.0 is in tmp_dic keys or not? I have a simple logic like this, but seems it can return wrong answer sometimes.

```
str(int(1.0)) in tmp_dic.keys()
```

Do I need to check if numeric string is integer or float before checking if they exists in the keys?
Thanks for the hints.

Comment: That depends on whether you want floats and integer string representation to be considered as equal?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "wrong answer sometimes"?  P.S. instead of using `in tmp_dic.keys()` just use `in tmp_dic`, it does the same thing but is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
def gen_float(l):
    for f in l:
        try:
            yield float(f)
        except ValueError:
            pass
any(v == 1.00 for v in gen_float(tmp_dic.keys()))
```

output:

```
True
```

is better to cast your keys to float than converting your check float to an `int`  than to a string, for ex. if your check float is `1.23` this will be converted to `1`

---

or you can use:

```
1.0 in gen_float(tmp_dic.keys())
```

as @HeapOverflow was suggesting

---

it will be better if at `tmp_dict` creation time you will try to convert the keys into floats, than the search for a `float` in your dict will be O(1) time complexity

---

if you do not have strings like `'1.0000'` you can also use:

```
str(1.0) in tmp_dict or str(int(1.0)) in tmp_dict
```

Comment: Doing a linear search of a dictionary kind of defeats the purpose of using a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: @MarkRansom the OP may have '1.00',  or '1.00000'  in which case a linear approach is a good approach

Comment: No, linear is not a good approach, it's a slow one.  If that's what you want to do, it would be more productive to have a `list` of key,value pairs.  The better approach is to make the keys be a consistent format so that equivalent keys always match.

Comment: P.S. using floats as dictionary keys isn't a good idea either, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987

Comment: I m pretty sure the OP hasn't this corner case, is more about 1 decimal, as I can see, but the OP may clarify

Comment: @kederrac- Thanks a lot. That works. And you are right. I have only 1 decimal.

Comment: @MarkRansom- Thanks for the comment. I agrrte with your point about using float in the dict. The float in the above example dict comes from output of pd.cut for binning a numerical value which I convert bins to a dict. Not sure if that is the best idea though.

Comment: what about using a decimal.Decimal?